Survival function for a certain population
If the survival function for a certain population is given by $$ s(x) = \left( \frac{1}{1+x} \right)^4 $$ for $x \ge 0$, how long would you expect a person who is $41$ years old to live?
(a) $14$ years
(b) $18.5$ years
(c) $20$ years
(d) $40$ years
(e) $42$ years
My attempt is as follows:
$$E\left[X>41\right]=\int _{41}^{\infty }\frac{x}{\left(1+x\right)^4}\:dx=\frac{31}{111132}$$
Which seems incorrect, please provide any sort of help, thanks.

You're missing all the reasoning and the working. You've just written an integral with a seemingly (albeit I realize it isnt) random fraction after an "=". That is not showing your work as I'd use the term. The idea with self study problems is we can offer guidance, not do your homework

Let's start from first principles.
The survival function $S(t)$ is the probability that the failure time $T$ is greater than $t$.  So
$$ S(t) = \Pr(T > t) \>. $$
We're interested in the probability that the failure time, $T$, is greater than $t$, provided $T>41$.  As a probability statement
$$ \Pr(T>t \mid T>41) $$
Using Bayes Rule...
$$ \Pr(T>t \mid T>41) = \dfrac{\Pr(T>t \cap T>41)}{P(T>41)} = \dfrac{\Pr(T>t+41)}{\Pr(T>41)} = \dfrac{S(t+41)}{S(41)}$$
Where $t$ is understood now to be years after age 41. The expected remaining lifetime is then found by integrating this expression over remaining $t$.  So, we need to compute
$$ \int_{t=0}^{t=\infty} \dfrac{S(t+41)}{S(41)} \, dt $$
Using some computer algebra, it looks like the integrand is
$$\dfrac{3111696}{(42 + t)^4}$$
and integrating this function yields an answer of 14
So we expect the person to live an additional 14 years.
